# Changing page name and bots: was anyone able to talk with a real person?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

We have wasted a lot of time trying to change the page name. We have attached evidence that the mark is ours and the denunciation that prevents us from continuing to use the current name, and the answers were incoherent.

Eventually we have realized that we have been "talking" with BOTS very well made. The bots sometimes responded soon and sometimes took several days as if they were real people.

Has anyone been able to talk with a Facebook representative? How?

Screenshot of my conversation with the bot:

[image: conversation with bot]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if anyone would be able to help you here about Facebook representative or not.

In my opinion, [Report a Problem](https://www.facebook.com/help/android-app/165775630241697/) to Facebook and probably they will come back to you.